# Sqlite output mode

Tags: sqlite, cmd

At first I put the output mode to column and it works fine... then I change the mode to ASCII it didn't change the last line and after that when I try to change it again to column it printed in one line.
Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Report this on the [sqlite-users mailing list](http://mailinglists.sqlite.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/sqlite-users).

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in the `sqlite3` command-line shell (`.mode ascii` changed both row and column separators, but `.mode column` changed only the column separator back).

This will be fixed in version 3.17.

Comment: And apparently (from the mailing list),  doing `.mode csv` then `.mode column`  _will_ switch back correctly (in 3.16.2 on Linux and possibly other versions).